# Finding the partial differential equation arising from a surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Find the partial differential equation arising from following surface
$$u=f(x-y).$$

Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ gives $u_x=1.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
and
Differentiating w.r.t. $y$ gives $u_y=-1.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$
Then, Eliminating $f′$ gives $u_x+u_y=0$

**But, I dont understand how to eliminate them, because first is derivative w.r.t $x$ and second is derivative w.r.t $y$**? Please clarify the logic behind it.

Comment: $f$ is a one variable function, like $f(t)$, we have $f'(t)$ where $t=x-y$.

Comment: Might be useful to give the derivative a new symbol: say $g(x) = f'(x)$. Then note that $u_x = \frac{\partial f(x-y)}{\partial x} \equiv \left[f'(t)\right]_{t=x-y} \cdot \frac{d(x-y)}{dx}  = g(x-y) \cdot 1$. The same calculation for $u_y$ gives $g(x-y)\cdot(-1)$ so the two sum to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T=T(x,y)$ be the function $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ defined by $T(x,y) = x-y$. Clearly $\partial_x T = 1 = -\partial_y T$. We apply chain rule,
$$ \partial_xu=\partial_x f(x-y) = \partial_x [f\circ T(x,y)]=f'(T(x,y))\partial_xT(x,y) = f'(x-y)$$
and
$$ \partial_yu=\partial_y f(x-y) = \partial_y [f\circ T(x,y)]=f'(T(x,y))\partial_yT(x,y) = -f'(x-y)$$

Answer (score 1):

When you differentiate partially with respect to $x$, you treat $y$ as a constant. So you can think $x-y=g(x)$.$$\partial_x f(x-y)=\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=f'(x-y)\partial_x (x-y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: when you differentiate by $x$ you consider $y$ constant and vice versa. Thus, when you apply the chain rule you'll get either $f'(x-y)$ or $-f'(x-y)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don' t still understand. How can we get $f'(x-y)$ or $-f'(x-y)$ by chain rule?  Could you explain more explicitly?